# Navigate to a specific component from parent (React Native Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Noob question about React Native Navigation.

This is my App.js. When I launch it, I see Component1.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  myFunction(){
    /*
      -------------------------------------------
      Navigate from Component1 to Component2 (???)
      -------------------------------------------
    */
  }

  render(){
    return(
          <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Component1" component={Component1} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Component2" component={Component2} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

}

export default App
```

From the same class, inside myFunction, I want to navigate to **Component2**. How to do it?

All the guides I found, explain how to do it inside the **Component1**, using the navigation props. I need to do it from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Component2")
```